# How to install in a docker container an old version of a r package

Tags: r, docker, package, version

How can I install ggplot2 2.2.1 within a docker container?

The command lines

```
RUN R -e "install.packages('devtools', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')"
RUN R -e "devtools::install_github('http://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/archive/v2.2.1.tar.gz')"
```

in the Dockerfile gives me the error:

```
The command '/bin/sh -c R -r "devtools::install_github('https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/archive/v2.2.1.tar.gz')"' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

If I remove the line

```
RUN R -e "devtools::install_github('http://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2
```

no error appears. I also tried different approaches to install ggplot2 2.2.1 but all led to the same result/error.

Comment: Have you tried explicitly defining the Dockerfile location using  docker build -f? This is a commonly overlooked detail that returns the error you received.

Comment: Doesn't work...same error. Without RUN R -e "devtools::install_github('http://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/archive/v2.2.1.tar.gz')" I can build an image

Comment: Now I have come to the conclusion that devtools is not installed correctly. Obviously additional packages are required under linux which I still have to find out. These are installed at the beginning:
    gdebi-core \
    pandoc \
    pandoc-citeproc \
    libcurl4-gnutls-dev \
    libcairo2-dev \
    libxt-dev \
    libssl-dev \
    libxml2-dev

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem by changing the command

```
RUN R -e "install.packages('devtools', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/', dependencies = TRUE)"
```

Now devtools is installed appropriate.